# Handle UBL 2.1 invoices - .net 6

Tags: .net, ubl

I'm starting a research task for handling UBL 2.1 invoices in a .net 6 project.

From a quick research there seems to be a "popular" .net library , namely [UblSharp](https://github.com/UblSharp/UblSharp).

Unfortunately, it seems it hasn't been updated from a long time, last release was on May 2019.I understand that UBL 2.1. is a standard from November 2013, so the current UblSharp should still work as expected.

But i'm not very enthusiastic of using a third party library, that isn't maintained anymore. Moreover, once we need to use UBL 2.2 or higher, we will need a different approach, as UblSharp only works up to 2.1.

Another approach could be to manually create the C# classes needed to handle UBL 2.1, for example, using something like XmlSchemaClassGenerator
https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator

From a theorethical prespective (and please understand that i'm just starting the research, so i might be wrong), by creating specific .net classes to handle
the [UBL 2.1 specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd) should allow me to easily handle UBL 2.1 invoices.

I'm tempted in going with XmlSchemaClassGenerator approach.

**Am i missing anything or being over simplistic?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the end, i opted to test all alternatives:

1. Direct XSD to c# classes with [LinqToXsdCore](https://github.com/mamift/LinqToXsdCore)
2. Third party libs: [UblSharp](https://github.com/UblSharp/UblSharp) and [UblTr](https://github.com/hkutluay/UblTr)

**Direct XSD to c# classes with LinqToXsdCore**

I've used the UBL 2.1 specification available on the [OASIS documents](https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/prd1-UBL-2.1/).
When generating the Invoice classes from the [UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/prd1-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd) i got some errors:

- Generated code doesn't compile if an element is named Content: known error described in the [LinqToXsdCore Github](https://github.com/mamift/LinqToXsdCore/issues/45).
- Some methods were failing due to the return type, but this was easily fixed.

**Third party libs**

Both UblSharp and UblTr were simple to use.
*UblSharp*  isn't maintained since 2019, but given that the UBL 2.1 specification is from 2013, it shouldn't matter.

*UblTr* was updated on Dec/2023, but seems to be specific for Turkey.

Both handled the [UBL 2.1 Invoice example](https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/prd1-UBL-2.1/xml/UBL-Invoice-2.1-Example.xml) file perfectly.

I did a very crude benchmark, and direct c# classes from xsd, and UblSharp (around 70-90ms) are more or less equivalent, with UblTr with higher process times (around 400ms).